# how to make Footer buttons appears while dragging screen down in android like in facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, footer, gesture

I wanna make footer buttons in android one way is to simply make buttons and align them to bottom but I want the footer like in Facebook android app whenever we drag screen down three buttons appears for status , photo , checkin.

How to do this ??

Comment: I don't have the application in front of me, but I would assume that all they do for this effect is align the buttons at the bottom, showing them on a touch event and then do a post delayed handler to hide it after several seconds.

Answer (score 3):

To get a list like the following image, create a `layout.xml` as follows after the sample image

[image: sample demo for the xml file]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/BtnSlide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_drawable" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg_drawable"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_btn_small" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/headerText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnSlide"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:editable="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/filterNewProject"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnSlide"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_input_blue"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:hint="Search for a locality, developer or project"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearAutoCompleteList"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_clear"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/seaerch_glass" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabBar"
            android:background="#d5d5d5"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        layout="@layout/post_requirement_footer"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/projectsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="1.5dp" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/zeroResultsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emptyIllustration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/no_results_illustration" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.housing.utils.QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomListViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_bg" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/filterButtonFooter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg_drawable"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filter_icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/subscribeButtonFooter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg_drawable"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/subscribe_iphone"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resultsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/resultsText"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filter_normal"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.housing.utils.QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter>

</RelativeLayout>



Here is the Class com.housing.utils.QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter 
PS : Replace com.housing.utils with your package name


package com.housing.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter extends RelativeLayout implements
        OnScrollListener {

    private class ChildDescriptor {
        public int index;
        public int total;
        public int drawable;

        public ChildDescriptor(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public int getApproximateScrollPosition() {
            return index * total + (total - drawable);
        }
    }

    public int MAX_HEIGHT_DP =60;
    public int MIN_HEIGHT_DP = 0;

    public static final int SCROLL_DIRECTION_INVALID = 0;
    public static final int SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP = 1;
    public static final int SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN = 2;

    private int direction = SCROLL_DIRECTION_INVALID;

    private ChildDescriptor lastchild;

    private OnScrollListener onscrolllistener;

    private int maxheight;

    private int minheight;

    public QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        calculateMinMax();
    }

    public QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        calculateMinMax();
    }

    public QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        calculateMinMax();
    }

    private void calculateMinMax() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        maxheight = (int) (metrics.density * (float) MAX_HEIGHT_DP);
        minheight = (int) (metrics.density * (float) MIN_HEIGHT_DP);
    }

    private void adjustHeight(int howmuch, int max, int min) {

        if ((howmuch < 0) && (direction != SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP)) {
            direction = SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP;
            return;
        } else if ((howmuch > 20) && (direction != SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN)) {
            direction = SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN;
            return;
        }

        int current = getHeight();
        current += howmuch;
        if (current < min) {
            current = min;
        } else if (current > max) {
            current = max;
        }

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams f = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        if (f.height != current) {
            f.height = current;
            setLayoutParams(f);
        }

        if (direction == SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP
                && Math.abs(f.topMargin) <= current) {
            // if (f.topMargin != howmuch) {
            //
            // f.topMargin = howmuch + f.topMargin;
            //
            // if (f.topMargin > 0) {
            // f.topMargin = -f.topMargin - 10;
            // }
            //
            // }
            // mBottomListViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            f.bottomMargin = -100;
            setLayoutParams(f);

        } else if (direction == SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN) {

            if (f.bottomMargin != 0) {
                f.bottomMargin = 0;
                setLayoutParams(f);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        ChildDescriptor currentchild = getFirstChildItemDescriptor(view,
                firstVisibleItem);
        try {

            adjustHeight(lastchild.getApproximateScrollPosition()
                    - currentchild.getApproximateScrollPosition(), maxheight,
                    minheight);
            lastchild = currentchild;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            lastchild = currentchild;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (onscrolllistener != null) {
            onscrolllistener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount,
                    totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    private ChildDescriptor getFirstChildItemDescriptor(AbsListView view,
            int index) {
        ChildDescriptor h = new ChildDescriptor(index);
        try {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            View child = view.getChildAt(0);
            child.getDrawingRect(r);
            h.total = r.height();
            view.getChildVisibleRect(child, r, null);
            h.drawable = r.height();
            return h;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        if (onscrolllistener != null) {
            onscrolllistener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
        }
    }

    public void attach(AbsListView view) {
        view.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener l) {
        onscrolllistener = l;
    }

}


I Have made it as a widget and Now finally to add this to your List View use

frame = (QuickReturnRelativeLayoutFooter) newProjectsView
                .findViewById(R.id.frame);
        frame.attach(projectsList);

where projectList is your List View
example

ListView projectList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.projectList);

and Voila Cheers Completed Smooth as Heaven .......
```

Comment: A little strange on scroll sometimes, but overall pretty good!